# Move the chart when new point is added

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Is there any way to show the latest point on highcharts chart after using setData method? I always have to manually move it.

I found that zoomOut(); does it, but, obviously, it affects the zoom.

I have 16 series on the chart.

Clarification: I would like the chart to be in the same state after adding the new data point, as if it was always there. That is, moved maximum to the right.

When a new chart is created, latest point is always visible (you can scroll back to see older points, but you can always see the latest one) that is unless overriden of course.

Comment: What do you mean "manually move it"? By default, the lastest point should always be shown when added. Unless you have a max on your x axis that excludes it. In that case, remove the max setting.

Comment: when new point is added, I have to click on the chart, and move my mouse to the left to show the new point.

Comment: You'll have to provide an example, or at least your code, so we can see why - that is not the normal behavior.

Comment: New points added, main chart not moving: http://jsfiddle.net/eqnpLx6q/

Comment: Remove a setExtremes which overwrite min/max values on xAxis. Fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eqnpLx6q/7/

Comment: Can you please take a look at this example which is closer to my real problem: http://jsfiddle.net/eqnpLx6q/8/ - click on 'add' -> you have to move the chart manually @SebastianBochan

Comment: Why you use a setData instead of addPoint?

Comment: because it's not updated at regular intervals and sometimes there might be  several hundred points to add. There are 16 series to update. It's easier to just set new data.

Answer (score 1):

I would fix this by adding a

```
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes();
```

To the end of your `updateData()` function, which forces the axis to adjust to the new data.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/eqnpLx6q/9/

Comment: It appears that chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(); resets the zoom (if 1 day is selected, and default is 1 month, it resets it to 1 month)

Comment: This is the best solution, call a setExtremes. This reset zoom because zoom is also a setextremes only. So you need to prepare a calculation of min/max values.

Comment: To expand on Sebastian's comment - instead of calling setExtremes() with no parameters, call it with the appropriate min and max that you will have to calculate from your data and your desired range.